# ec2-attach-volume Required option '-K, --private-key KEY' missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I get the following error when I followed [1] in order to add an EBS volume to an instance.

ec2-attach-volume
Required option '-K, --private-key KEY' missing (-h for usage)

[1]docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html

Comment: What command are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Sound like your are missing the environment variables for your AWS keys. Assuming you are using Unix/Linux try:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<your user AWS access key>
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<your user AWS secret access key>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What version of ec2-attach-volume are you using? The `-K` option is deprecated. can you run `ec2-attach-volume -h` and see if says something like: `-K, --private-key KEY
          [DEPRECATED] Specify KEY as the private key to use`